# Google Instance Id Server validation gives 401 error

Tags: server-side, verification, instanceid

I want to verify the app authenticity. To do that I want to use Google Instance Id. Using the instance id documentation i created an instance id token. I got instance id token for a dummy app(created only to get instance id Token). After getting this token I tried to validate the token using curl. The code is

> curl -H "Authorization:key=AIzaS...."  https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/instanceIdToken

The Authorization key, I got in google-services.json:: api_key: current_key category.

It sends a 401 unauthorized error. 
Kindly guide me what i am doing wrong here

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? Having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also got same issue, but this works fine if you generate token using [FirebaseInstanceId](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId) instead of [GoogleInstanceID](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID)

Tried on Android device..